# How is it possible to highlight all lowercase letters vith vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

After frequency analysis of a simple substitution cipher I have partially decoded string. I want to highlight all already decrypted letters which are lowercase (all not decrypted letters are uppercase) so I could focus on detecting words.

How is it possible with vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First enable highlighting search results, then do a search:

```
:set hlsearch
/[a-z]/
```

Comment: You could also do `/\l` which is shorter.